# OAuth 2.0 Server for PHP

Tags: php, security, oauth-2.0

I have been struggling to find an active open-source PHP project that supports OAuth 2.0 as a server. There are tons of client examples that connect to Facebook, Twitter, etc. but as more and more people want to expose their own services through an API I'm a bit surprised the open source community hasn't addressed this need already. It's not that there is **nothing** but what's there is mostly out-of-date, little-to-no documentation, and very little to no activity in terms of current development and conversation.

Am I missing a good open-source option out there? Does anyone know of any commercial options? I really need to get something in place soonish and I personally don't have the bandwidth or security credentials to tackle this problem myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much searching around I believe I have found the best solution for PHP'ers out there. Opinions are a dime a dozen but here's my favourite:

http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

Very active, high quality conversation and a solid product along with good (and improving) documentation.

Comment: Is this library still recommended to use in 2018?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the list of available server and client libraries:

http://oauth.net/2/

which leads to a [github project](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) which is maintained.

Comment: Strange. I had been at your previous link and don't remember finding the project you pointed to. On first glance it looks pretty good. The documentation that exists is good but there's still a lot untouched. Still its the best example I've seen so far. I may have swim with the code for a while to see if I can understand how to use this effectively.

Comment: There are one more project on github, which has lots of things done, such as interfaces applications and permissions manager: [https://github.com/fkooman/php-oauth](https://github.com/fkooman/php-oauth)

Comment: Have you used either? Do you have any recommendations? How much stable do you find the code to be?

Comment: Didn't use them much, actually. We were planning to provide oAuth on our service, so I had to find a proper library to implement that. But then planned changed, and I had to switch to another tasks, so I didn't have enough time to test those libraries in a real project. :(

Answer (score 2):

[oauth2 server by php league](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) is much more followed and downloaded project on github. My personal experience has been awesome and the best part is it's documentation. Excellent implementation of oauth2.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.zimuel.it/oauth2-apigility/ & http://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2

You now can implement OAuth 2.0 Server using the open source project Apigility, with Brent Shaffer's implementation underneath...

in the end...

> The OAuth2 implementation in Apigility uses the oauth2-server-php
>   library by Brent Shaffer. Apigility uses a PDO database to store all
>   the information related to the OAuth2 protocol. You can create your
>   database using the schema reported in the file
>   /vendor/zfcampus/zf-oauth2/data/db_oauth2.sql under your Apigility
>   installation folder (zf-apigility-skeleton).