# Zend Framework 2 and OAuth how to create provider?

Tags: oauth, zend-framework2

I'm looking for a way to secure my own api with OAuth, but all I find is how to create client that connects to Twitter or Facebook. In the ZF2 docs site there is only example how to use ZendOAuth to connect to Twitter service. Is there any tutorial/documentation or anything ?

Answer (score 2):

Which version about Oauth you are looking for ?

Just add one of these modules to create an Oauth provider. *Take care! you have to know how oauth works, to integrate into your application.*

**For oauth 1.0a**
https://github.com/bgallagher/BgOauthProvider

**For oauth 2.0**
https://github.com/php-loep/oauth2-server

Answer (score 0):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23302428/389976

Essentially check out Apigility http://www.apigility.org/