# MySQL access through PHP from ASP website (as there is no direct TCP access)

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, web-hosting

I'm about to run an ASP website on a hosting server which gives no sql, but another one with PHP and MySQL. The problem is remote access to MySQL is denied. Is there any possible ways to connect it with, so client-side can access the database using PHP or something?

Comment: Well, you could create a websercice in the PHP end that accepts and incoming string containing SQL and returns another string containing the results encoded (i.e. with JSON). It could lead to some security problems, but it should work

Comment: i need to use the server for login purpose, so can you please specify any other method for secure transfer.

Comment: Well, you could allways sign the requests on the ASP and verify the signature from de PHP end.

Comment: i'm new to PHP, can you explain with some samples or link to those samples of coding? Thanks a lot and in advance.

Comment: I'm affraid it would be more expensive to apply this solution than to pay for a hosting with a database...

Comment: but actually, both are free, so the coding is the only part. I just have to program it myself, but which encrption method is safe to transfer, how to use the cgi? are the things i need to know.  But one more thing i've in mind is using the iframe at the website to get the data at required places is whether a good idea or not?

Comment: How is the server running MySQL set up? You might be able to get a secure connection to the database using tried and tested tools like stunnel or SSH port forwarding, and then be able to connect using ASP. I don't recommend trying to "roll your own" secure connection using a PHP proxy. However, if what you're trying to build is a "single sign on" service for the two applications, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643956/oauth-2-0-server-for-php

Comment: the MySQL server is a free hosting, just like the ASP hosting and its denying remote access to the database.  So I would like to build up a website on ASP, but need the MySQL for database connectivity, so only way is the PHP, is there any way to use the cgi system to have a token access for the website to access the database?